# sass command not working

Tags: sass

I have something stupid: I installed haml with bundle and did a "bundle install". The gem is installed, it is in the local gem list. When I then do "sass --watch style.scss:style.css" then I get: "'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command". What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute commands from the gems in the bundle, you can use `bundle exec`. In your case e.g. `bundle exec sass --watch style.scss:style.css`.

Comment: Worked for me too. I wish we didn't have to use bundle exec... not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I installed sass with:

```
$ sudo gem install sass
```

Then you can just run:

```
$ sass --watch ftw.scss:ftw.css
```